# How to write CSS comment emmet in VScode?

Tags: css

I have been commenting on CSS files using the formal way but now  I decided to take the advantage of Emmet in vs code.
know I should use /*  */ but I want to know how can I comment on the CSS files using VSCode Emmet.

Comment: No need to use `emmet`, since there is shortcut available `ctrl` `+` `/`

Comment: Also, when pasting your question in google I get the answer straight away: https://docs.emmet.io/actions/toggle-comment/

Answer (score 1):

Just use the shortcut `ctrl` + `/` it will comment out the whole line based on your context. There is no need to use Emmet!

This is common in most of major IDEs!